# The Born-Oppenheimer approximation and muonic molecules

Tags: many-body, quantum-chemistry, born-oppenheimer-approximation

Does the [Born-Oppenheimer approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born-Oppenheimer_Approximation) fail for muonic molecules (i.e. molecules where one or more electrons are replaced with muons)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Deepends on your definition of "fails". The accuracy of Born-Oppenheimer approximation is determined by  the smallness of the electron/nucleus mass ratio. For hydrogen this ratio is $\approx 1/1800$. Replace the electron mass by the muon mass, which is 200 times larger, and you get $\approx 1/9$ which gives you a rough estimate for the relative accuracy in case of muonic molecules.

Comment: Which means, the approximation still works, but convergence is much slower, You need more calculation loops.

Comment: @Georg: Well, most of computational chemistry never goes beyond the 0th order of Born-Openheimer;  So $1/9$ is really 200 worse news than $1/1800$. OF course, it all depends on the particular problem.

Comment: Is it a power expansion or something exponential like $1+e^{-\frac{a}{\epsilon}}+...$, $\epsilon = m_e/m_{nucl}$ (why is it called an "adiabatic" approximation)?

Comment: @VladimirKalitvianski: BO treats nucleai as static and allows separation of (fast) electron dynamics and (slow) nucleus dynamics. Going beyond BO requires taking into account nucleus-electron entanglement and thus greatly expands the Hilbert space that need to be approximated.  See more on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born%E2%80%93Oppenheimer_approximation).

Comment: I did not find the answer. Is it a series like $1+a\epsilon+...$ or not? Where does that $1/9$ stand?

Comment: @VladimirKalitvianski: $\epsilon=1/9$ is my estimate of $m_{\mu} /m_{\rm{proton}}$. The order of non-adiabatic corrections to the BO, depends on how far you are from degeneracy. Away from term crossings I'd expect $1+a \epsilon$, while in the vicinity of adiabatic degeneracy's the vibronic (higher order) effects can results in qualitatively new classification of states (strong mixing of vibrational and electron degrees of freedom).

Comment: @Slaviks: So it is a power expansion in $\epsilon$, nothing adiabatic, isn't it?

Comment: @VladimirKalitvianski: I'm happy to say yes! "Adiabatic" just happens to be one of the more heavily used and therefore abused words in physics.. Textbooks on BO are full of statements like "electrons follow the movement of the nuclei *adiabatically*", which is correct statement under a proper quantum mechanical definition of adiabaticity. Perhaps we need a separate thread on the terminological issue with "adiabaticity".